# VB.net how to get the value from my user control textbox

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I do have a project for daily monitoring, and I have a problem getting the text from my textbox wherein my textbox is in my usercontrol.

the scenario would be, if I click the show button, the userControl.vb would be called in my panel and I dont have a problem putting up userControl.vb to my panel, if I click save button which will check if all fields are fill-up before saving the data. I would save as normal and wont check my panel where I load up my userControl.vb

this my snippet project tree:

```
DXApplication
|_My Porject
|_User Control <folder>
  |_userControl.vb <user control form>
|_frmMainActivity <winForm>
```

here is my code for loading the userControl in my Panel

```
Friend ctrlUser As UserControl

ctrlUser = New userControlx
ctrlUser.Dock = DockStyle.Top
pnlActivity.Controls.Clear()
pnlActivity.Controls.Add(ctrlUser)
```

here is code for calling the textbox from userControl from another sub to check if the code can get the text.

```
*edited the userControl should be userControlx*
Dim uc As New userControlx
Msgbox(uc.txtLatitude.text)
```

when i hit the trigger button to show what text i put on my textbox i would return msgbox with empty string.

Any suggestion? where did I go wrong on calling the value of the textbox?

I've tried using:

```
Dim uc As New userControlx
uc.txtLongitude.text = "Test Text"
msgbox(ux.txtLongitude.txt)
```

It will return the  **Test Text**, But in my UI the textbox that is loaded is empty.

Comment: uc is creating a new instance of the user control. Shouldn't you be attempting to inspect the value in ctrlUser ?

Answer (score 0):

in the trigger button you create a new instance of `userControl`, thats why the content of your textbox is emtpy

instead use

```
Msgbox(ctrlUser.txtLatitude.text)
```